# Combining two MS Access queries

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this query:

```
SELECT "I1" & "," & "I2" AS Item_set, Round(Sum([T1].Fuzzy_Value)/Count(*),15) AS Support
    FROM (SELECT *
    FROM Prune AS t
    WHERE t.Trans_ID IN 

        (SELECT t1.Trans_ID FROM (

         SELECT *FROM Prune WHERE [Nama]="I1")  AS t1 
         INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Prune WHERE [Nama]="I2")  AS t2 ON t1.Trans_ID = t2.Trans_ID)

    AND t.Nama IN ("I1","I2"))  AS T1;
```

And ttrans query

```
SELECT Count([Trans_ID].[Trans_ID]) AS Expr1
FROM Trans_ID;
```

I need to change `Count (*)` from :

```
 SELECT "I1" & "," & "I2" AS Item_set, Round(Sum([T1].Fuzzy_Value)/Count(*),15)
```

into ttrans query.

I've tried using

```
SELECT "I1" & "," & "I2" AS Item_set, Round(Sum([T1].Fuzzy_Value)/ttrans.Expr1,15) AS Support
FROM (SELECT *
FROM Prune AS t
WHERE t.Trans_ID IN 

    (SELECT t1.Trans_ID FROM (

     SELECT *FROM Prune WHERE [Nama]="I1")  AS t1 
     INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Prune WHERE [Nama]="I2")  AS t2 ON t1.Trans_ID = t2.Trans_ID)

AND t.Nama IN ("I1","I2"))  AS T1, ttrans;
```

But I got error like this :

```
You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 
'Round(sum([T1].Fuzzy_Value/ttrans.Expr1,15)' as part of an aggregate function
```

any idea how to fix it?

**Note** : I'm trying to find 2 combination of all item in transaction database and get a result like this

```
ITEM       Support
I1, I2     0.xxxxxxxxx
```

where support is (total transaction containing item I1 and I2 / total transaction) -> note that I'm using ttrans query to get total transaction value

**note2:** I'm using MS Access
**note3:**

Ttrans table will look like this

```
Expr1
270200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

somehow i find the answer :

i tried using

```
SELECT "I1" & "," & "I2" AS Item_set, Round(Sum([T1].Fuzzy_Value)/sum(ttrans.Expr1),15)
```

it worked wonder

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT "I1" & "," & "I2" AS Item_set, Round(Sum([T1].Fuzzy_Value)/ttrans.Expr1,15) AS Support
FROM (SELECT *
FROM Prune AS t
WHERE t.Trans_ID IN 

    (SELECT t1.Trans_ID FROM (

     SELECT *FROM Prune WHERE [Nama]="I1")  AS t1 
     INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Prune WHERE [Nama]="I2")  AS t2 ON t1.Trans_ID = t2.Trans_ID)

AND t.Nama IN ("I1","I2"))  AS T1, ttrans
GROUP BY "I1" & "," & "I2"
```