# Combining Aggregate Queries

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have Two Tables of related data.

- Table 1 - All Trading history by broker
- Table 2 - All Trade Breaks (trades which had errors / differences / issues)

I created a Query to Total the number of trades by Broker from Table 1

I created a Query to Total the number of "Breaks" by Broker from Table 2

I then created a Query to combine the two previous Queries and produce some statistics

Example:

```
Broker       Total Trades        Total Breaks       Break %
Goldman         10                    4               40%
Morgan          10                    2               20%
```

Rather than create 3 queries - is there a way to create 1 query which achieves the same result? I want to perform more detailed analysis / reports without inundating the database with tons of individual queries. SQL Code Below

**First Query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW [All Breaks].Broker, Sum([All Breaks].TradeCount) AS   
[Sum Of TradeCount]
FROM [All Breaks]
GROUP BY [All Breaks].Broker;
```

**Second Query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW [All Trades].Broker, Sum([All Trades].TradeCount) AS  
SumOfTradeCount
FROM [All Trades]
GROUP BY [All Trades].Broker;
```

**end Result: Combining**

```
SELECT [Broker List].Broker, [All Breaks Query].[Sum Of TradeCount], [All  
Trades Query].SumOfTradeCount, [Sum Of TradeCount]/[SumOfTradeCount] AS  
Percentage
FROM ([Broker List] INNER JOIN [All Breaks Query] ON [Broker List].Broker  
= [All Breaks Query].Broker) INNER JOIN [All Trades Query] ON [Broker  
List].Broker = [All Trades Query].Broker;
```

Thanks Very Much!

Comment: To be honest - some of the ways I navigated around problems like these (because Access isn't as powerful as some of the newer RDMS), was to put these query results in temporary tables. You can then use the result sets as table data and not have to be restricted by any of Access' SQL restrictions (which you may or may not run into)

Comment: Without trying to replicate, I'd say your work looks very good.  SQL analysis does rely on stacking or nesting, and sometimes it feels you are "inundated", but consolidating into fewer objects often costs you a lot in ability to maintain the code.

Comment: Why are you using DistinctRow? Thx.

Comment: As for the use of temporary tables, I treat that solution as a last resort.  My guess is that you prolly don't need them at this point.

Comment: Emmad - the code used was based upon the Query Tool.

Answer (score 0):

In query design, there is a way to switch to SQL View, where you can freely write sql.

`select one, two
from
(select one, joinfield from table1) as first
Inner join (select two, joinfield from table2) as second 
  ON first.joinfield = second.joinfield.`

Also, see [Combining two MS Access queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439369/combining-two-ms-access-queries?rq=1)